# Websphere profile and application deployment

Tags: websphere, profile

My Websphere server has two Profiles and I want to deploy same application in both profiles. How these two applications will be accessed. Is each profile have different port to access it, so will differentiate the access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each profile has its own ports (check the AboutProfile.txt file in the profileName/logs directory). So the URLs will be probably host:9080/context and host:9081/context. By default ports are incremented by one.